# Accessing table data via jquery(coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a table of Users. This is a row of the HTML:

```
<td class=" ">
   <a href="#" data-user="20" data-bb="confirm" class="confirm-user bb-dialog btn btn-success btn-mini">Confirm</a>
</td>
```

I'm trying to update a field in the User record via this coffee script:

```
$(document).ready ->
  userid = null

  $(".confirm-user").click ->
    bootbox.dialog "Are you sure you want to Confirm User?", [
      label: "Confirm"
      class: "btn-success"
      callback: ->
        userid = $(this).data('user')
        alert userid
        $.ajax
          url: "/users/" + userid
          type: "POST"
          data:
            _method: 'PUT'
            user:
              confirmed_at: new Date,
          success: (resp) ->
            window.location.reload()
    ,
      label: "Cancel"
      class: "btn-danger"
      callback: ->
        return 'false'
    ]
```

But, the `alert` is giving me undefined for `userid`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context for `$(this)` has changed.  Try storing a reference to it before entering the callback:

```
$(".confirm-user").click ->
  $this = $(this)
  bootbox.dialog "Are you sure you want to Confirm User?", [
  ...
    userid = $this.data('user')
```